# Extracting forms XML into dropbox folder

Tags: sharepoint

Have a client with a fairly recent SP2007 deployment and want to use it as a means of managing some manual data collections using basic InfoPath Forms (all nice out of the box stuff). When a form is submitted/saved I want to be able to get the XML out and saved on a shared folder somewhere so I can pick it up from their standard DataStage ETL platform - is such functionality an out of the box configuration with SP (and if so can someone point me at the docs?) or will we have to construct some kind of service interface?

Cheers,
Mark

Answer (score 1):

In Infopath, you can configure your form to be submited to:

- Email
- SharePoint library
- WebService
- Server (HTTP Post)
- Data connection ([SQL](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/infopath-help/submit-form-data-to-a-microsoft-sql-server-database-HP010107060.aspx)...)
- Custom code...

One solution would be to submit the form to a SharePoint library.
And use "[Explorer view / WebDav](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/copying-or-moving-sharepoint-document-libraries-HA001154465.aspx)" to get the XML.

Comment: We've currently got a rough prototype that just publishes the forms to a document library - we'd like a way to have that either pushed (copied) out onto a shared drive in XML format; or pulled (via DataStage and a WebService?) into a shared drive as XML. If we can avoid writing any code at all in the SP environment we can sidestep a whole shedload of SDLC headache ;) so I was hoping there was some standard method for achieving this. Ideally whatever method would trigger on submission of a form rather than having to poll/track etc...